# tiny_mce_before_init is not trigger

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to Clean up pasted text in WordPress and so I've decided to followed the instructions of [this tutorial](https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2015/02/19/clean-pasted-text-in-wordpress/).

It seems simple just to add a filter on `before_wp_tiny_mce` and add a setting to clean the text.

My issue is that `tiny_mce_before_init` is never triggered. I can see these hooks trigger : `before_wp_tiny_mce`, `wp_tiny_mce_init`, `after_wp_tiny_mce` but never `tiny_mce_before_init`.

I've looked everywhere nothing has removed the filter, no extension to replace tinymce.

If anyone has an idea ?

Edit, here is the code (i've tried to put it in the function.php of my child themes where others hooks are and working) :

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init','configure_tinymce');

/**
 * Customize TinyMCE's configuration
 *
 * @param   array
 * @return  array
 */
function configure_tinymce($in) {
  $in['paste_preprocess'] = "function(plugin, args){
    // Strip all HTML tags except those we have whitelisted
    var whitelist = 'p,span,b,strong,i,em,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,li,ol';
    var stripped = jQuery('<div>' + args.content + '</div>');
    var els = stripped.find('*').not(whitelist);
    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var e = els[i];
      jQuery(e).replaceWith(e.innerHTML);
    }
    // Strip all class and id attributes
    stripped.find('*').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
    // Return the clean HTML
    args.content = stripped.html();
  }";
  return $in;
}
```

Comment: There's no code in your question, can you edit your question to add it? Also where is the code? The location and **when** it loads is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the contents of `class-wp-editor.php`, it looks like `tiny_mce_before` only triggers if you are not using the Teeny version of the editor:

```
/*
 * For people who really REALLY know what they're doing with TinyMCE
 * You can modify $mceInit to add, remove, change elements of the config
 * before tinyMCE.init. Setting "valid_elements", "invalid_elements"
 * and "extended_valid_elements" can be done through this filter. Best
 * is to use the default cleanup by not specifying valid_elements,
 * as TinyMCE checks against the full set of HTML 5.0 elements and attributes.
 */
if ( $set['teeny'] ) {

    /**
     * Filters the teenyMCE config before init.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param array  $mceInit   An array with teenyMCE config.
     * @param string $editor_id Unique editor identifier, e.g. 'content'.
     */
    $mceInit = apply_filters( 'teeny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id );
} else {

    /**
     * Filters the TinyMCE config before init.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param array  $mceInit   An array with TinyMCE config.
     * @param string $editor_id Unique editor identifier, e.g. 'content'.
     */
    $mceInit = apply_filters( 'tiny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id );
}
```

If the config can work for both Tiny and Teeny, you could hook on both filters to modify the configuration.

Comment: thanks ! i'll try it and let you know, i did notice the teeny/tiny settings but i was very far to think that changes hooks logical too ...